# some space between spans

Tags: html, css

I want to add some space between two spans. Margins and paddins dos't work. How can I do that?

```
<a href="some.action>

    <span style="display: block; width: 460px; height:55px">

        <span style="float:left">
            <img src="uploads/image.jpg" />
        </span>

        <span style="float:left">
            <span style="color:#286c9b">name</span>
            <br/> <!-- Нow make this space bigger? Margins and paddins does not work.-->
            <span>other name</span>
        </span>

    </span>
</a>
```

Comment: Why do they have to be spans when you want them to act like divs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `display:block` to the span you want to add the margin to:

```
<span style="float:left">
    <span style="color:#286c9b; display:block; margin-bottom:20px">name</span>
     <br/> <!-- Нow make this space bigger? Margins and paddings don't work.-->
      <span>other name</span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
span {display:inline-block; margin:10px;}
```